# Insert a "scale box" of given side length in the QGIS layout?

Tags: qgis, scale, layouts

QGIS allows displaying a scale bar, indicating distances. I would like to complement it with a box showing a given area, e.g. 1 hectare. How can I display this in a layout, ideally as an extension of the scale bar?

Example:

```
.----------------.

|........1ha.......|   

'-----------------'    100   -----------------    200   -----------------    300 -----------------      400    -----------------   500 m
```

Comment: If it is not possible directly you could create the box as a polygon of 100x100m size and display that in a separate map widget.

Comment: What is wrong with 100m - 1 segment long scale bar? Do you absolutely need to have square? Maybe the thickness of scalebar can be scale driven too, not sure.

Comment: This question was closed as needing details or clarity. It's not my question, but it seems very clear to me what the poster was looking for, perhaps since I have seen such maps in the past. I have edited to add some detail in the hopes it will thus become clearer to reviewers in the reopen queue. The good answer already provided is consistent with my interpretation, but perhaps there are other solutions. Please edit further if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 5):

Create a rectangle using the corresponding tool in the map composer.

[image]

Make sure it is equal sided, the side ratio is locked and you are using `mm` as unit (you can set this in the properties of the layout item).

Then you must use `data defined override` for the size of the rectangle (hit the button showing two stacked rectangles with tiny triangles attached next to the field where you can enter the size of the item). Choose `edit` and enter the following:

```
round(100000/map_get(item_variables('Karte'),'map_scale'))`
```

`item_variables` accesses an item of your layout, in this case the map. I called it `Karte`, you have to change its name in the expression according to how you named your map.

`map_get` retrieves some attribute of the chosen item, in this case the scale.

The side of a rectangle with an area of 1 ha is 100 m long, and 100 m = 10,000 cm = 100,000 mm. Dividing this number by the scale tells us, how many mm at our current map scale equal 100 m in real life.

I added the `round(...)` since the value retrieved by the expression is slightly off (as in the scale is returned as 1:10,000.000017). The error might be very small, but anyway.

After you entered this expression for both sides of the rectangle, its size will fit your current scale. If you change the scale, the rectangle **will not** scale automatically. You have to access the data defined override again, choose edit and confirm the expression. Only then the rectangle will rescale, so I suggest you do this as the very last step before exporting your map.

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer to add a scale bar, to make copies, to modify and to combine them like in the demo:

[image]

I added a gif because it would take a long time to write and explain.

Comment: Definitely +1 for the fancy gif.